# REst API for Uploading Files

Tags: php, api

Can anyone help me how to use this function below... This function will upload file into to my storage but unfortunately I didn't know how to use the code. i tried numerous times already but still it doesn't work. This code is not mine I got it from github and try to  use it into my project.

```js
public function upload(){

  // Check that the path is a directory
  if(is_file($this->path)){ 
    $this->status = "error";
    $this->message = "Path Not A Directory";
  }else{
    // Handle upload
    $target = $this->path  . "/" . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      $this->status = "success";    
    }else{
      $this->status = "error";
      $this->message = "Upload Error";
    }          
  }
  $this->respond();        
}
```

```html
<form action="file.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" name="path" value="class/" readonly>
  <input type="file" name="upload" readonly>
  <!--  <input type="submit" name="create" class="btn btnsuccess btn-
                     sm" value="create dir/file ">
              <input type="submit" name="open" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
                      value="Open a file">
              -->
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="upload to specific dir">
  <!--  <input type="submit" name="modify" class="btn btn-success 
                      btn-sm" value="modify file or dir">
              <input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
                     value="delete file">
              <input type="submit" name="index" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
                     value="list dir">
              <input type="submit" name="dublicate" class="btn btn-success btn-
                    sm" value="duplicate"> -->
</form>
```

url: `http://localhost/api/archiving%20system/file.php?action=upload&path=class%2F&upload=myfile.txt`

OUtput: `{"status":"error","message":"Upload Error"}`

Comment: can you link to where you got it from

Comment: _"but still it doesn't work"_ - What happens? Do you get any response from the server? Error messages? Where is `$this->path` set? Is the path correct? Is it writable?

Comment: Can you tell us how it is going wrong? Or why you juts don't find more code & try that? Did you breakpoint it in your IDE and step through it to see what went wrong?

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory to which you want to move the files? See https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/move_uploaded_file-faq   I recall once having to change something in my Php.ini to get `move_uploaded_file()` to work, but I forget what. Google around, I am 99% sure that your problem is with `move_uploaded_file()` - and note that it might work on `localhost`, but not on your server, if they have different settings - which can make it more difficult to debug

Comment: Btw, `is_file($this->path)` is not enough of a check, since it will return true in case the path doesn't exist at all (which will make your `move_uploaded_file()` to fail).

Answer (score 4):

You need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` added to your `<form>` tag - and it should probably be `POST` for the method and not `GET`, and a max file size...

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
     <input type="hidden" name="action"  value="upload" readonly>
     <input type="hidden" name="path"  value="class/" readonly>
     <input type="file" name="upload" readonly>
     <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="upload to specific dir">
</form>
```